# Play Audio - iOS Não Toca o Som - Atraso na Saída do Som

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

Tenho essa função para carregar, remover, startar e pausar o áudio.

```
media = (function(){
    return{
        create : function(name, src){
            mediaData[name] = new Audio();
            mediaData[name].src = baseURL+'/media/'+src;
            mediaData[name].volume = .5;
        },
        remove : function(name){
            if(mediaData[name]){
                delete mediaData[name];
            }
        },
        play : function(name){
            return mediaData[name].play();
            if(!Modernizr.touch)
                mediaData[name].currentTime = 1;
        },
        stop : function(name){
            mediaData[name].pause();
            if(!Modernizr.touch)
                mediaData[name].currentTime = 0;
        },
        replay : function(name){
            if(!Modernizr.touch)
                mediaData[name].currentTime = 0;
        }
    }
})();
```

Mas no **Safari** do **iPad** estou tendo problemas. Alguns áudios carregam e funcionam, já outros não tocam. E nos outros navegadores funcionam normalmente.

O que será que pode ser ?

Um exemplo de como chamo o áudio via **JS**.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  media.play("chime-01"); /////////////// FUNCIONA
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div#gift").addClass('anime');
    var randomGift = Math.floor((Math.random() * totalGifts) + 1);
    var gift = $('div#gift > .gifts > div:nth-child(' + randomGift + ')');
    gift.addClass('active');
    setTimeout(function() {
      gift.addClass('rotate');
      //Frase do objeto
      var audio = gift.data('audio');
      setTimeout(function() {
        media.play(audio); ////////////// NÃO FUNCIONA
      }, 1400);
    }, 2000);
    media.play("tada");
  }, 100);
}, 250);
```

No código acima comentei a linha que o áudio funciona e na linha que não funciona no iOS - Safari - iPad.

Mas nos outros navegadores funcionam as duas linhas. Então, antes que alguém alegue, o caminho do áudio está certo, as variáveis com seus valores também.

---

Estava lendo na documentação do Safari e encontrei isso:

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it.

**Traduzindo:**

No Safari no iOS(para todos os dispositivos, incluindo iPad), onde o usuário pode estar em uma rede celular e ser cobrado por unidade de dados (3G, 4G), o pré carregamento e autoplay são desativados. Nenhum dado é carregado até o usuário o iniciar.

E agora ? Não tem jeito pra isso ?

Comment: O return nåo deixa o código chegar ao "if" para verificar o modernizr. Já reparaste nisso?

Comment: O `return` do `play` ? Sim, eu reparei. Eu tirei, mas não deu certo.

Comment: Percebi também que no navegador o som funciona com atraso.